# Calling a windows forms application file in vb from a c++ project

Tags: vb.net, visual-c++

I have a `windows forms application` file which extracts data from a text file and then stores it in suitable variable lists. This list needs to be accessed by another project file of mine in `visual c++`. Can this be done or do I need to write one of my codes again in the same language?

Say my `form1` has a list variable `product` of type `string` that needs to be accessed by a project file `Software` written in visual studio's `c++` language code. I want to access product in Software for further usage.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add your VB project as a reference of your C++/CLI project and its classes should be available to use in your C++/CLI code.
(right click on your C++ project, select Add, Add references and then Projects).

Comment: Sorry about that, I made a mistake, its working but the point still remains that the data that i want to access is later. I need to activate the form first so that the data may be extracted. Like, in vb we have a  Form.Show()  function, I need a similar function that allows me to first start my form and after the form's task is complete the variables in which the data is stored needs to be accessed.

Comment: can you give a more concrete example/sample of your code please?

Comment: Actually I cannot share the code but can be a little more specific. I Have A vb file that extracts data from a text File and Then Stores the Data In a List variable of type String. But this is an intermediate step of a bigger program. Hence, I want to run my form from the bigger program's cpp file, then after the work there is done, take data stored by it back in cpp

Comment: so if you have your VB project as reference, can you simply not call form1.load event?